# Change date format from m/dd/yy to yyyy/MM/dd in Java

Tags: java

I have this Date in a String with a 2 digit year.
I need to convert in another format. I tried with SampleDateFormat but it didn't work.
The SampleDateFormat is giving wrong format i.2 date with UTC and timestamp
I want in yyyy/MM/dd only.
Is there any other way to do this?

```java
String receiveDate = "7/20/21";
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
try {
    rdate = sdf.parse(receiveDate);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
String recievedt = rdate.toString();
String dateParts[] = recievedt.split("/");
// Getting day, month, and year from receive date
String month = dateParts[0];
String day = dateParts[1];
String year = dateParts[2];

int iday = Integer.parseInt(day);
int imonth = Integer.parseInt(month);
int iyear = Integer.parseInt(year);
LocalDate date4 = LocalDate.of(iyear, imonth, iday).plusDays(2*dueoffset);
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to make it readable (format your code nicely).

Comment: don't start with a String, start with an actual Date(Time) object

Comment: What version of Java are you using? Are you able to use the java.time APIs?

Comment: Date is coming from database in String

Comment: my recommendation: step 1, fix your db design

Comment: A couple of things: 1) I strongly recommend you start using the `java.time` API with its formatters, 2) "The SampleDateFormat is giving wrong format" - no, you're using `SimpleDateFormat` to parse the string into a `java.util.Date` and then call `toString()` on it which returns the _default_ representation of the date. You'd need to use another formatter to produce the output you want. 3) Your date string `"7/20/21"` doesn't seem to match the format `"yyyy/MM/dd"` you're using to parse - you should fix that as well.

Comment: java 8 @ChrisCooper

Comment: Are you sure that the input string is in the format "y/MM/dd" (1 digit year, 2 digits month, 2 digits day)? "7/20/21" looks more like "M/dd/yy" (month, day, year).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can use the `java.time` API I would suggest something along the lines of the following:

```
String input = "7/20/21";
LocalDate receivedDate = LocalDate.parse(input, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/dd/yy"));
String formatted = receivedDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd"));
// or if you actually need the date components
int year = receivedDate.getYear();
...
```

Comment: OP mentioned that she uses java 8, also there is a small issue in your code

Comment: No, actualy this solution worked @AshishMishra

Comment: @MansiMandal yes Chris corrected the formatting of date

Answer (score 0):

How is `String receiveDate="7/20/21";` a valid date?

```
String dateStr = "07/10/21";
SimpleDateFormat receivedFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yy/MM/dd");
SimpleDateFormat finalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
Date date = receivedFormat.parse(dateStr);
System.out.println(finalFormat.format(date));  // 2007/10/21
```

This, however, requires that you have date with leading zeros for year, month and date. If that is not the case, please sanitize your date string.

```
public static String sanitizeDateStr(String dateStr) {
    String dateStrArr[] = dateStr.split("/");
    String yearStr = String.format("%02d", Integer.parseInt(dateStrArr[0]));
    String monthStr = String.format("%02d", Integer.parseInt(dateStrArr[1]));
    String dayStr = String.format("%02d", Integer.parseInt(dateStrArr[2]));
    
    return String.format("%s/%s/%s", yearStr, monthStr, dayStr);
}

public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
    String dateStr = sanitizeDateStr("7/10/21");
    SimpleDateFormat receivedFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yy/MM/dd");
    SimpleDateFormat finalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    Date date = receivedFormat.parse(dateStr);
    System.out.println(finalFormat.format(date));
}
```

Comment: I believe that it is not correct, and also it is not the recommended way. Use `DateTimeFormatter` and other classes from java.time for formatting and parsing dates. Not `SimpleDateFormat`, not `String.split()` and not `String.format()`.